# оформление заказа в Sylius Bundle

Tags: symfony2, sylius, bundles

добавление\удаление из корзины работает. Данные записываются в таблицу `sylius_order`. Но какие условия должны быть соблюдены чтобы **order** стал заказом? (перестал отображаться в корзине у клиента и появился в админке как новый заказ).

пробую менять статус заказа на `pending`, но заказы в админке не отображаются.

вот пример записи из таблици `sylius_order`

```
[
    {
        'id' : 39,
        'shipping_address_id' : NULL,
        'billing_address_id' : NULL,
        'user_id' : 17,
        'number' : NULL,
        'email' : 'username@mail.ru',
        'state' : 'cart',
        'completed_at' : NULL,
        'items_total' : 200,
        'adjustments_total' : 0,
        'total' : 200,
        'created_at' : '2015-08-07 15:57:28',
        'updated_at' : '2015-08-10 11:58:10',
        'deleted_at' : NULL,
        'expires_at' : '2015-08-07 18:57:28',
        'currency' : 'UAH',
        'payment_state' : 'cart',
        'shipping_state' : 'checkout'
    }
]
```

как совершить покупку используя этот бандл? Хочу из корзины заказ переместить в новые заказы.
документация не сильно помогла

---

[sylius docs](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/orders.html) не сильно помогли разобраться как работает бандл, а примеров работы с бандлом не нашел

[Статусы Order](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/components/Order/order_states.html)

возможно кто-то уже имеет опыт работы с данным бандлом и поделится опытом или примерами кода c **github**.

Answer (score 1):

на основе сорцов

```
/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/Checkout/Step/PaymentStep.php
```

пытаюсь создать из `оrder'a` **->** `payment`

```
    public function paymentAction(Request $request) 
    {

        $cartProvider = $this->container->get('sylius.cart_provider');
        $order = $cartProvider->getCart();
        $paymentStep = $this->container->get('event_dispatcher');
        $paymentStep->dispatch(SyliusCheckoutEvents::PAYMENT_INITIALIZE, new GenericEvent($order));
        $form = $this->createForm('sylius_checkout_payment', $order);
        if ($form->handleRequest($request)) {
            $paymentStep->dispatch(SyliusCheckoutEvents::PAYMENT_PRE_COMPLETE, new GenericEvent($order));
            $orm = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
            $orm->persist($order);
            $orm->flush();

            $paymentStep->dispatch(SyliusCheckoutEvents::PAYMENT_COMPLETE, new GenericEvent($order));

            return new ActionResult();
        }
        return JsonResponse::create(true);

    }
```

в таблице `sylius_payment` появилась запись

```
 id, method_id, credit_card_id, order_id, currency, amount, state, details, created_at, updated_at
'2', NULL, NULL, '46', 'UAH', '10', 'new', '[]', '2015-08-14 12:22:40', '2015-08-14 12:22:47'
```

`order_id` 46 в таблице `sylius_order` не изменился. Сгенериная админка вообще никаких заказов не видит